# Removing double XML nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net, dtd

Here is an example of XML-file consisting of a root-element, parent and child nodes. I was looking for the best way to remove doubles of nodes (when necessary), and I tried lots of tricks and ways to do it: like `childNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(childNode)` etc., but every method I tried, was not working properly (or I did something wrong, or maybe because of DTD; I'm not sure). Well, I found an alternative way to do it and I thought: maybe it could be interesting to share with other people.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root[
  <!ELEMENT root (parent, child)>
  <!ELEMENT parent (child)>
  <!ELEMENT child EMPTY>
]>
<root>
  <parent>
    <child />
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child />
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child />
  </parent>
</root>
```

Comment: Whilst asking and answering your own question is allowed, we do encourage you to ensure that the question, by itself, is an answerable **question**. At the moment, I'm looking at this and have no idea what you mean by "doubles of nodes". What makes a node a double? I assume the XML you're showing us is the input - what should the corresponding output be and why? Try to make sure your question actually describes the problem and *asks* a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but it seems you simply want to remove all `parent` nodes besides the first two?.

Then how about simply:

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load(pathToLoad)

For Each parent in xml.<root>.<parent>.Skip(2).ToList()
    parent.Remove()
Next 

xml.Save(pathToSave)
```

Comment: I have edited the original code when placing my Question-Answer, and I made a mistake when converting original variable names and node names to easier ones.

Comment: And yes. It's not a question. It's a Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Do`-`Loop` instead of `For`-`Next`, because I got errors when using `For`-`Next` loop: e.g. `child` nodes were removed, together with `parent` node attributes (which you don't see in this example) but `parent` nodes still remained. But using `Do`-`Loop` I get an expected result (if you want to remove all `parent` nodes besides the first one, then write `Loop Until i = 0` instead of `Loop Until i = 1`. In my example I need first two `parent` nodes):

```
Dim i As Integer = MyXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parent").Count - 1
   Do
      MyXmlDocument.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(MyXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parent")(i))
      i -= 1
   Loop Until i = 1
MyXmlDocument.Save(MyXmlFile)
```

The whole code is, as follows (I declared 'XmlReader', 'XmlSettings' and 'XmlDocument' within a module, outside of methods to be able to use them outside of module. And `LoadSettings()`is called by `Form.Load` Event. One more thing must still happen: when an error exception happens while loading `XmlDocument`, `XmlReader` stays open. Maybe by adding Finally : `MyXmlReader.Close()`, this "issue" will be solved.

```
Public Module Common

   Public MyXmlFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Common\myxmlfile.xml"
   Public MyXmlReader As Xml.XmlReader
   Public MyXmlReaderSettings As New Xml.XmlReaderSettings
   Public MyXmlDocument As New Xml.XmlDocument

   Public Sub LoadSettings()
      MyXmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse

      If File.Exists(MyXmlFile) Then
         Try
            MyXmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(MyXmlFile, MyXmlReaderSettings)
            MyXmlDocument.Load(MyXmlReader)
            MyXmlReader.Close()


            If MyXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parent").Count > 2 Then 
               Dim i As Integer = MyXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parent").Count - 1
               Do
                  MyXmlDocument.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(MyXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("parent")(i))
                  i -= 1
               Loop Until i = 1
               MyXmlDocument.Save(MyXmlFile)
            End If
         Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)   
         End Try
      End If
   End Sub
End Module
```